# "Multiplayer/Singleplayer" vs "The multiplayer/The singleplayer"

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

In my experience, when we talk about a mode in a video game, we don't use the definite article, "the." I wonder if it is correct to use the definite article before game modes. Do you think the versions with and without the definite article are interchangeable in the sentences below?

> I play *multiplayer*/*the multiplayer* of Modern Warfare.

> I play *singleplayer*/*the singleplayer* of Modern Warfare.

> Do you play *multiplayer*/*the multiplayer* in Modern Warfare?

> Do you play *singleplayer*/*the singleplayer* in Modern Warfare?

Comment: The main problem I see with using an article is that *multiplayer* is an adjective, not a noun, so it sounds weird to say "the multiplayer".  We can sometimes use adjectives as nouns (as in "Eat *the rich*") but those uses usually seem more appropriate because of age.

Answer (score 1):

It would certainly be better to phrase the first sentences as

> I play Modern Warfare in multiplayer/single-player mode.

To wit, single-player is usually not written unseparated.

For the second sentence jumble I'd also prefer

> Do you play the multiplayer/single-player mode of Modern Warfare?

Other than that, the usage of the definite articles the way you portrayed it leads to a peculiar sentence cadence.

Answer (score 0):

Multiplayer and single-player are both adjectives. They need a noun. Try adding "mode" or "game" to the sentences.

> I play a single-player game of modern warfare. 
> Do you play modern warfare in multiplayer mode?

Answer (score 0):

The grammar in both of the cases in your question is incorrect. I think you mean -

> I play the multiplayer mode in Modern Warfare

Vs

> I play multiplayer mode in Modern Warfare

We use “the” when the object in question is *specific*.

So

> I play the multiplayer mode in Modern Warfare

Is the correct one.

If the Multiplayer game mode has more specific variants say 2v2, 3v3 then you can say

> I play the 3 v 3 multiplayer mode in Modern Warfare

Because now 3v3 is the specific object, that we have to give “the” to.

Answer (score 0):

Do you think the versions with and without the definite article are interchangeable in the sentences below?

*My Answer is no they are not interchangeable and the sentences all sound incorrect in any variation.*

---

> 1. I play multiplayer of Modern Warfare. or 1a. I play the multiplayer of Modern Warfare.

Both sentences sound awkward, play and multiplayer is basically repeating yourself with consecutive words. Modern warfare is not specific, unless you have already highlighted the topic. Therefore we should state that it is a game and we are going to name it so we write  "**The** game blah blah" So **yes we may use the definite** article albeit in a different way to which you have tried to use it (see my answer to items 3 & 4). Finally you have made a definite statement you always use multiplayer mode, never ever single-player. Although this could be true I would use a less definite tone.

*I use the multiplayer mode of the game Modern Warfare*,
alternatively (*presuming the reader knows Modern Warfare is a game*), what I think sounds better in spoken English is;

**I prefer multiplayer mode when playing Modern Warfare**

---

> 2. I play singleplayer of Modern Warfare or 2a. I play the singleplayer of Modern Warfare

again as in Item 1

**I prefer single-player mode when playing Modern Warfare**

---

> 3. Do you play multiplayer/the multiplayer in Modern Warfare?

and

> 4.Do you play single-player/the single-player in Modern Warfare?

I would replace with

**When playing the game Modern Warfare, which mode do you use, Single or Multiplayer?**

---

**The definite article** We use the definite article in front of a noun when we believe the listener/reader knows exactly what we are referring to: So here we have used the noun Game and the name of the game so no one is doubt of what we are talking about.

In your examples you had tried to use the definite article with the **"adjective multiplayer".** which is incorrect. [**The definite article: 'the'**](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/definite-article-the)

---

**multiplayer**; adjective; used to refer to computer games in which several players can compete against each other:

Ref; CED [**multiplayer**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/multiplayer)

**game**; noun; game noun (FUN ACTIVITY/SPORT) an entertaining activity or sport

Ref; CED [Game](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/game?q=game%20)